# Get uploaded image (Resource) from back-end and display it as image in angular7

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, angular7, multipartform-data

I want to display the data of a bottle on my website, this one contains a variable string which is actually the path where the image is stored in back end.
I want to be able to manipulate this resource in angular then display the image obtained in html

I can make the request from the front end, then I don't know how to receive it

request to the back end (via service)

```
getBottleImage(path): Observable<File[]> {
    return  this.http.get<File[]>('http://localhost:8762/image/downloadFile/' + path);
}
```

Here are my two functions of upload and get (back end):

Store file :

```
public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
    // Normalize file name
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
        if(fileName.contains("..")) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
        }

        // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
        Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        logger.info("targetLocation " +targetLocation);
        return fileName;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new FileStorageException("Impossible de stocker le fichier" + fileName + ". S'il vous plait réessayez !", ex);
    }
}
```

Get File :

```
public Resource loadFileAsResource(String fileName) {
    try {
        Path filePath = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName).normalize();
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
        if(resource.exists()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new MyFileNotFoundException("Fichier non trouvé" + fileName);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new MyFileNotFoundException("Fichier non trouvé " + fileName, ex);
    }
}
```

postman shows me the result directly (either a .txt or .png file)

```
https://ibb.co/2n7yd2j
```

So I think it's a front end problem..

Comment: Is the issue you're having with receiving the request on the back-end, or receiving the response on the front-end?

Comment: from front end https://ibb.co/pjdLPnL this is my error

Comment: Funny. A successful HTTP call is logged as an error.

Comment: Kindly pass correct method with correct response , also need to show reponse image tag 

like..<img src="http://domain/controller/imagename" alt="">

Comment: very well, but in this case what is the correct method and the correct response?